# Como utilizar tags em MySQL e PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Eu estou a criar um site e gostaria de saber como posso utilizar tags com MySQL e PHP.

Eu tenho duas tabelas: `produtos` e `informacao`.

Na tabela `informacao` tenho um campo chamado produtos relacionados onde vou colocar os produtos separados por virgulas, como posso depois pegar esses nomes sem as virgulas para que possa fazer uma pesquisa com cada um deles?

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?
$explode = explode(',',$relacionados);
foreach($explode as $nome){

    $result = $connection -> query("select * from produtos where titulo='$nome' and linguagem='$lang'");
    while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $titulo = $row['titulo'];
        $resumo = $row['resumo'];
        $imagem = $row['imagem'];
        $categoria = $row['tags'];
?>

        <div class="grid_3">
            <div class="box2 wrap1 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                <a href="verproduto.php?id=<?=$id?>&lang=<?=$lang?>" id="produto"><img class="first" src="<?=$imagem?>" alt=""/></a>
                <div class="caption bggreen equal">
                    <h6 class="text_3 colorblue">
                        <a href="verproduto.php?id=<?=$id?>&lang=<?=$lang?>"><?=$titulo?></a>
                    </h6>
                    <br>
                    <p class="colorwhite">
                    <?=$resumo?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?
}}
?>
</div>
<? 
$result -> free();
?>
```

Com este código apenas consegui imprimir o segundo produto relacionado que foi onde a *string* fez o `explode`, preciso de imprimir todos os produtos e não onde ele parte.

Comment: Aconselho a criar uma tabela para as tags e depois associar as tags.

Comment: Não é mais fácil fazer um relacionamento 1:n, ao invés de separar por vírgulas?

Comment: E se tiver mais que uma tag?

Comment: produtos => [id, nome] | informacao => [texto, tag_id] | tag => [id, nome]

Comment: Até ai tudo bem, agora eu na informação preciso que apareça os produtos relacionados ou seja preciso de pegar nas tags e pesquisar produtos com titulo=tag

Comment: Poste o DER do seu banco de preferencia, para que possamos entender.

Comment: Já vou adiantando: dar `explode` na vírgula para obter as partes é uma senhora gambiarra. Por isso recomendamos o relacionamento!

Comment: E se eu tiver várias tags para a mesma informação?

Comment: Márcio, é justamente pra isso que funciona o relacionamento 1:n . . . em outras palavras, 1 informação pode possuir nenhuma ou muitas tags

Comment: Já consegui fazer isso, estou agora com um outra dúvida. Não sei se posso colocar neste tópico. Como posso inserir dados no mysql vindo de checkboxes? Mas quero inserir uma linha por cada checkboxe selecionado, ou seja, se selecionarem 4 faz 4 inserts. É possivel?

Comment: Se você resolveu, poste uma resposta para sua solução e valide-a depois de dois dias. Se você tiver outro problema, crie uma nova pergunta.