# Como inserir TAGs num banco MYSQL usando PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

boa tarde! Eu possuo um sistema de base de conhecimentos onde cada usuário pode entrar lá e preencher um formulário e cadastrar o procedimento que ele sabe. Eu estou precisando implementar um campo de TAG nesse formulário de cadastramento de conhecimento, este campo será usado para futuramente o documento ser pesquisado. Cada documento quando é inserido no banco tem um ID único, a minha dúvida é:

OBS: A entrada de dados nesse campo de TAGS seria através de um CAMPO DE TAGS mesmo (Como é feito aqui no forum na hora de cadastrar a pergunta)

Como os dados serão inseridos no banco de dados mysql, uma vez que cada procedimento possui um ID único?
Exemplo: Procedimento 1 – Como usar o ipconfig – TAGS: Windows, rede, msdos.

***Como esses três valores de tags vão para o banco mysql? que possui um FIELD chamado TAGs ?***

Pelo que eu entendi no mysql os registros seriam + o – assim:

```
| id   |  procedimento_ nome   | tags                    |  
|  01  |  Como usar o ipconfig | Windows, rede, msdos    |
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Acho que é o mesmo problema dessa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48695/70 - de qualquer formam acho que precisa explicar melhor como é que a pessoa vai entrar com as tags no seu sistema. tem maneiras diferentes de se fazer, tudo depende de como vão ser usadas depois.

Comment: então, como eu disse, a entrada dos dados será feita no formulário de cadastro... a pessoa quando está cadastrando o documento ele terá um campo chamado TAGS (parecido ao que usamos aqui no forum quando vamos fazer perguntas) e aí essas tagas que ela cadastrou servirão para pesquisa posteriormente.

Comment: Entrada no cadastro pode ser um campo texto livre, pode ser um componente de escolha de tags, pode ser uma lista pré definida. Tem muitas maneiras que podem mudar a escolha. Pode ser que no seu caso uma tabela de tags ajude, pode ser que compense fazer direto em campo texto. Dependendo como for a pesquisa por tag varia o jeito de organizar também. São todos esses (e outros) detalhes que podem mudar as respostas, e poderiam estar no corpo da pergunta para evitar que fique ampla demais. Sugeriria [edit] e descrever melhor os requisitos e funcionamento (isso ajuda a obter respostas mais precisas)

Comment: seria tipo criar uma array das tags e colocar no banco de dados? e na hora da pesquisa por tags o usuario escolhe uma e no sql procuraria por artigos com a tag escolhida?

Comment: Em princípio, sem os detalhes que mencionei no comentário anterior, seria só mandar o campo de tags da mesma forma que qualquer outro campo de texto. Já tentou isto? Que alternativas tentou, e quais foram as dificuldades encontradas?

Comment: Então Bacco, eu realmente não estou sabendo me explicar, mas pelo que entendi o que eu preciso seria realmente essa questão de fazer um relacionamento 1:n... pq eu iria armazenar todas as tags que o cliente cadastrou no banco relacionada a aquele documento x... tipo TAG1 -> Doc1 | Tag2 -> Doc1 | Tag3 -> Doc1 ... Vou pesquisar como criar esse relacionamento!

Comment: @IgorSantana se você editar a pergunta explicando melhor o que quer fazer primeiro, a comunidade tem como te ajudar. O problema da pergunta não descrever o problema especifico atual é que corre o risco de responderem coisas que não é o que você espera. Pode ser que um leitor se preocupe com a parte do insert, outro com a interface de edição das tags e como receber e processar o que veio no form, e um terceiro com a parte do relacionamento. Se conseguir concentrar a pergunta em um problema só, ajuda. Depois que resolver cada passo, abre + perguntas.